# Transfer Function Block Diagram Confirmation

Tags: z-transform

Can someone confirm if this is the correct block diagram for the following transfer function?

The original equation provided was: y[n+1] = y[n] + 0.01x[n]

Which I rearranged into H(z) = Y(z)/X(z) = 0.01 / (z - 1) and then also rearranged into y(n) = y(n-1) + 0.01x(n-1)

And left me with the following block diagram,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is *a* correct way to do it, but leaves you with (depending on what you're trying to do) an excess of delay blocks.  This also works:

[image]